# When does the Endorsement Policy take place? What are the relevant System Chain Codes?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I referenced the web page : http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arch-deep-dive.html

And I want to ask you about this picture and Endorsement Policy.
[image]

In section 2.3 of the website, the following statement appears. And that is related to ③ of the picture.

> "The exact number of “enough” depend on the chaincode **endorsement
>   policy**"

And in section 2.4 of this web site, the following statement appears for a peer. that is related to ④ of the picture.

> It checks that the blob.endorsement is valid according to the **policy
>   of the chaincode** (blob.tran-proposal.chaincodeID) to which it refers.

Question

1. What is the difference between an ③ endorsement policy and ④ a policy of
   the chaincode?
2. Is ESCC related to ③, and ④ related to VSCC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question
>
> 1. What is the difference between an ③ endorsement policy and ④ a policy of the chaincode?

At stage 3, the peer actually proceed with endorsement, meaning literally signing the results of the chaincode invocation. While at 4 this is happens at commit time, where peer ensures whenever endorsement policy satisfied.

**NOTE**: It's up to the client to collect required number of endorsements.

> 2. Is ESCC related to ③, and ④ related to VSCC?

Yes, [ESCC](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.1/core/scc/escc/endorser_onevalidsignature.go#L17) or Endorsement System ChainCode is the actually a system chaincode which responsible to "endorse" transaction, where [VSCC](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.1/core/scc/vscc/validator_onevalidsignature.go#L17) or Validation System ChainCode is a system chaincode to check whenever endorsement policy satisfied.

Comment: At stage 3, is not the client, the peer proceed with an endorsement?